# What is the method to factor $x^3 + 1$?

Tags: factoring

In the solution to a problem, it's stated that

> We see that $x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$.

Why is this, and what method can I use for similar problems with different coefficients?

The full problem is

> Find the remainder when $x^{81}+x^{48}+2x^{27}+x^6+3$ is divided by $x^3+1$.

Comment: Try to use long division.

Comment: By inspection, I think the answer is 2.

Comment: Cf. answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3338889/please-explain-the-formula-for-the-sum-of-the-cubes-and-the-difference-a3-b)

Comment: Read your identity from right to left. And ask yourself why it is true. And your answer will be to multiply the two factors and finding out that the result is $x^3+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the full problem: let be $$y=x^3.$$ Your problem is equivalent to find the remainder
of
$$
P(y) = y^{27}  + y^{16}  + 2y^9  + y^2  + 3
$$
when it is divided by $$y+1.$$ By Remainder's Theorem, that remainder is given by
$$P(-1)=2.$$

Comment: For heaven's sake keep the punctuation *inside* the double dollars. Otherwise the next line will begin with a punctuation character :-)

Answer (score 1):

For the full problem, working modulo $x^3+1$ we have $$x^3=-1\implies x^{3n}=(-1)^n\implies x^{81}+x^{48}+2x^{27}+x^6+3=-1+1-2+1+3=2.$$

So no such factorisation is needed. But when it *is* needed, here's how to do it. By the factor theorem, the fact that $(-1)^3+1=0$ implies $x-(-1)=x+1$ is a factor. So try $x^3+1=(x+1)(ax^2+bx+c)$. We know $a=1$ from the $x^3$ coefficient and $c=1$ from the constant term, and the $x^2$ coefficient tells us $0=a+b\implies b=-1$.

Comment: Is "modulo $x^3+1$" something that I would understand better if I read up on polynomial rings?  I am simultaneously understanding and having my mind blown reading through your equation.

Comment: @MatthewDaly That subject would help, but for now it's sufficient to note that if $x^{3k}=(-1)^k(\operatorname{mod}x^3+1)$, as is certainly true if $k=0$, $x^{3(k+1)}=(x^3+1)x^{3k}-x^{3k}=(-1)^{k+1}(\operatorname{mod}x^3+1)$, completing a proof by induction. Or even simpler, since you want to find the remainder when dividing a polynomial function of $u:=x^3$ by $u+1$, you can just use the usual remainder theorem for division by linear factors to get a constant remainder.

Answer (score 0):

$x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$ is something one just knows, similar to how one knows that
$
x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2
$, or $
x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)
$

If you don't already know it, note that $(-1)^3+1=0$, which implies that $x-(-1)$ is a factor of $x^3+1$. Finding the second factor can be done through long division.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$
can be seen from our good friend geometric series:
$$\dfrac{r^n-1}{r-1} = 1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^{n-1}$$

Plug $r=-x$ and $n=3$

Answer (score 0):

Since $(-1)^3+1=0,$ we know that $x^3+1$ is divisible by $x+1$, which gives the following way:
$$x^3+1=x^3+x^2-x^2-x+x+1=x^2(x+1)-x(x+1)+x+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1).$$